# Is there a place where I can find official Korean subtitles for non-Korean movies

Tags: south-korea

I am living in South Korea and here, foreign movies in cinema are not dubbed (as it would be in some other countries like France) but subtitled in Korean.

Instead of learning Korean by watching Korean dramas and movies with English subtitles, I would like to do it the other way around: watch English movies with Korean subtitles.

I already have a collection of movies at home, and I probably can find amateur-made subtitles on Internet. But having learned English with French movies with English, I know that amateur work is far from perfection.

Hence my question:

**Question**: is there a place where I can obtain, for free or for a small price, the subtitles that Korean movie theaters use?

Comment: Buy or rent a local DVD of an English or American film?

Comment: The point of my question is that I already have the movies. And a country where professional subtitles are made for all foreign movies and people used to read them (having to read subtitles would deter many French people), so there is a chance that these subtitles are available somewhere waiting for me to use them. Renting a DVD is the plan B.

Comment: So you're going to interlace Korean subtitles with an existing movie file/DVD?

Comment: On movie files mostly. With professional subtitles, if the beginning is well synchronized, the rest should be quite well-synchronized.